# Zooming an image in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, zooming

I'm currently developing a website using PrimeFaces component library. I would like to know, is there any built in component for zooming (zoom in and zoom out) an image in PrimeFaces?

Comment: If you didn't find anything in their showcase or documentation, then there is likely none.

Comment: In their showcase, Only GMap supports zoom in, zoom out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite the same, but there are two Primefaces extensions, called [ImageAreaSelect](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/imageAreaSelect.jsf) and [ImageRotateAndResize](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/imageRotateAndResize.jsf) which give you (combined) the same functionallity.

The second extension lets you scale your image, which can be almost interpreted as zoomed.
Also take a look at that [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/imageRotateAndResize/basicUsage.jsf) as well.

Answer (score 0):

No. Right now there isn't any component like that in Primefaces.
However you have other Non Primefaces options, you can go for Javascript,Jquery or Flash.